# Can you use a RF remote with nRF24L01 and Arduino?

Tags: nrf24l01+, rf

I recently bought a 10 pack of RF transceivers (nRF24L01). I wanted to know if its possible to pair one with an RC drone controller. I can't seem to find any ways to do this through google.

If this helps:

My drone and its controller is called "Sky Viper v2400" and a link to where you buy it is: [https://www.amazon.com/Sky-Viper-01601-Streaming-Video/dp/B01D1HRXSK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D1HRXSK).

Thanks

Comment: Probably not. You'd have do dismantle the drone and find out what chip it uses. If it's the nRF24L01 or one of the Nordic SoCs with a built in nRF24L01, then it could be possible. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Even if you figure out that your drone uses the same proprietary protocol (/chip) you have to somehow determine the channel, pipes and every other piece of the radio's configuration for any (proper) communication to work.

Answer (score 1):

The nRF24 operates in the 2.4GHz frequency and implements a proprietary protocol so, even if I don't have much information on your particular drone/controller, I strongly doubt there's a chance you can use the nRF24 module to talk to your drone.